# dplyr: streamline creating matching and absolute difference variables

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply, data-manipulation

I have a dataset of friendships and characteristics of each individual, I'm trying to create variables that are if they match on the binary measures and what their absolute difference is for the continuous measures.

I can do this easily, but I was wondering if there is a different way to do it that is more streamlined than my method given that I have ~60 variables to do this with.

Sample Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "id.x  id.y    male.x  smoke.x drink.x everfight.x grades.x    male.y  smoke.y drink.y everfight.y grades.y
1   6   0   2   4   1   3   0   2   1   0   2
2   7   0   2   4   0   5   0   2   3   1   4
3   8   1   4   4   1   2   0   4   2   1   1
4   9   0   2   3   1   2   0   3   2   0   1
5   10  1   2   4   0   4   1   4   1   0   4", header = TRUE)
```

Here's what I've done:

```
dat <- dat %>%
       mutate(sex_match = case_when(male.x == male.y ~ 1,
                                    TRUE ~ 0),
              fight_match = case_when(everfight.x == everfight.y ~ 1,
                                      TRUE ~ 0),
              smoke_diff   = abs(smoke.x  - smoke.y),
              drink_diff   = abs(drink.x  - drink.y),
              grades_diff  = abs(grades.x - grades.y))
```

This gives me exactly what I want:

```
id.x id.y male.x smoke.x drink.x everfight.x grades.x male.y smoke.y drink.y everfight.y grades.y sex_match fight_match smoke_diff drink_diff grades_diff
 1    6      0       2       4           1        3      0       2       1           0        2         1           0          0          3           1
 2    7      0       2       4           0        5      0       2       3           1        4         1           0          0          1           1
 3    8      1       4       4           1        2      0       4       2           1        1         0           1          0          2           1
 4    9      0       2       3           1        2      0       3       2           0        1         1           0          1          1           1
 5   10      1       2       4           0        4      1       4       1           0        4         1           1          2          3           0
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with a loop or apply that identifies corresponding vairables and create the matching and absolute difference new variables in the sample output above.

**UPDATE**

Ended up using most of what Jon answered with and one part of akrun, here's what worked best for me:

```
non_binary <- dat %>% select(., contains(".x")) %>%
                      select(., -id.x) %>%
                      select_if(~!all(. %in% 0:1)) %>% 
                      rename_with(~str_remove(., '.x')) %>%
                      names()
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id.x:id.y), 
               names_to = c("var", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.+).(.+)") %>%
  mutate(match = if_else(var %in% non_binary, abs(x - y), 1L * (x == y))) %>%
  mutate(col_name = paste(var, ifelse(var %in% non_binary, "diff", "match"), sep = "_")) %>%
  select(-c(var:y)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col_name, values_from = match)
```

Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyr/dplyr approach. First I reshape to a long format with a row for each id/variable combination, with columns for each version. Then I can compare those for every pair at once, and reshape wide.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
non_binary <- c("smoke", "drink", "grades")
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id.x:id.y), 
               names_to = c("var", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.+).(.+)") %>%
  mutate(match = if_else(var %in% non_binary, abs(x - y), 1L * (x == y))) %>%
  mutate(col_name = paste(var, ifelse(var %in% non_binary, "diff", "match"), sep = "_")) %>%
  select(-c(var:y)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col_name, values_from = match)
```

Result, which could be appended to original data:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
   id.x  id.y male_match smoke_diff drink_diff everfight_match grades_diff
  <int> <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>           <int>       <int>
1     1     6          1          0          3               0           1
2     2     7          1          0          1               0           1
3     3     8          0          0          2               1           1
4     4     9          1          1          1               0           1
5     5    10          1          2          3               1           0
```

Comment: This works for the matches, but for the variables that aren't binary I was hoping to get the absolute difference between the two. In dat those would be smoke, drink, and grades (see the output from my original code)

Comment: Without knowing the data set, what do you think is a good way to know if a column is binary? Would you list those upfront? Would it work to check if it's all 1/0's?

Comment: Yes all the binary variables would be 1/0's (though a few might be NA if missing). Sorry I would post the real data but it's restricted access.

Comment: Edited with approach using known list of "non-binary" variables.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` with `across` which can do this with `dplyr/stringr` packages alone i.e. loop `across` the `.x` columns of 'male', 'everfight', then `get` the value of the corresponding `.y` columns to create the binary column, similarly do this on the other columns, and get the `abs`olute difference.  In the `.names`, replace the column name by making use of `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
   mutate(across(c(male.x, everfight.x ),
      ~ +(. == get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'x$', 'y'))),
       .names = "{str_replace(.col, '.x', '_match')}"), 
     across(c(smoke.x, drink.x, grades.x), 
         ~
       abs(. - get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'x$', 'y'))),
           .names = "{str_replace(.col, '.x', '_diff')}"))
```

-output

```
id.x id.y male.x smoke.x drink.x everfight.x grades.x male.y smoke.y drink.y everfight.y grades.y male_match everfight_match smoke_diff drink_diff grades_diff
1    1    6      0       2       4           1        3      0       2       1           0        2          1               0          0          3           1
2    2    7      0       2       4           0        5      0       2       3           1        4          1               0          0          1           1
3    3    8      1       4       4           1        2      0       4       2           1        1          0               1          0          2           1
4    4    9      0       2       3           1        2      0       3       2           0        1          1               0          1          1           1
5    5   10      1       2       4           0        4      1       4       1           0        4          1               1          2          3           0
```

---

Or may do this in a single `across` as well

```
dat %>% 
    mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), ~ {
       other <- get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'x$', 'y'))
    if(all(. %in% c(0, 1)) )  +(. == other) else abs(. - other)
       }, .names = "{str_replace(.col, '.x', '_diff')}"))
```

Comment: This also works, but instead of specifying the vairbales in across, is there a way to identify them by whether they are binary or not? I'm looking to match the binary variables and get the diff for the others (many more variables in the real dataset)

Comment: @L.Tucker yes, that can be done i.e. `across(where(~ is.numeric(.) && all(c(1, 0) %in% .)), ~ .`

Comment: @L.Tucker or use an `if/else` by looping across everything, but then have to change the column name also accordingly with `if/else`

Comment: @L.Tucker I updated the post with a single `across`.  Currently, I renamed everything as `_diff`, you can `rename` in the next step or use an `if/else`